# Pine script -How to write a script that detects eight similar consecutive candles

Tags: linux, sharepoint-online, pine-script, debian-jessie

Want to write a pine script that gives an alert after 8 consecutive similar candles and gives an alert after the 8th or on the 8th candle.

Comment: You can share a full script for this or suggest a source where i can get such information.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
greenCandle = close > open ? 1 : 0

cond = sum(greenCandle, 8) == 8

alertcondition(cond, title = "Alert", message = "8th green!")
```